# Select text with similar formatting Office JS

Tags: vsto, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I am passing days struggling to find a way using OfficeJS to have the same functionality offered in the Office application by this button.

Isn't there an out-of-the-box function or even a little snippet to do this?

Thanks!!

[Select similar formatting button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtihd.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API in Office.js i recommend you to start a feature request in user voice.
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/